# sending custom dimension through google tag manager

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a Google Tag Manager implementation in my iOS app for sending events (user actions in the app)to a Google Analytics account. Along with these events, I wish to send a custom dimension as well with the events (this custom dimension has a value of "Online" or "Offline", depending upon whether the user is connected to the internet or not). This is how I do this:

```
- (void)pushToGtmDataLayer:(NSDictionary*)dataDict
    {
    if(dataDict) {
        if([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]networkReachabilityStatus] != AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown) {
        NSString *dimensionKey = [GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:6];
        if(dimensionKey) {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDataDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dataDict];
            BOOL online = [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]isReachable];
            NSString *dimensionVal = online ? @"Online Traffic" : @"Offline Traffic";
            tempDataDict[dimensionKey] = dimensionVal;
            dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tempDataDict];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"<<<PUSHING TO GTM DATA LAYER: %@", [dataDict description]);
    [[[TAGManager instance] dataLayer] push:dataDict];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"<<<EMPTY DICT TO PUSH TO GTM DATA LAYER");
    }
}
```

Example of a dataDict

```
    {
     "&cd6" = "Offline Traffic";
     EventAction = AppOpen;
     EventCategory = AppLaunch;
     EventLabel = "fresh launch";
     event = AppLaunch;
   }
```

Is this the right way to send a custom dimension with GTM?
Also note that, a different Google Analytics account (directly without GTM) is being used in tandem to report url loading metrics (time taken etc.). When I call NSString *dimensionKey = [GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:6],
which account does GAIFields refer to here, the one using the GTM for reporting user actions, or the one without GTM for url metrics?